# .net mvc 3: CreateEdit view not working

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, view

I learn .Net MVC and have a list with employees. Now I want to link to a view "CreateEdit", where I can create new employees or edit existing ones.

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcTest1.Domain.Model.Employee>
```

```
<html>

<head>
<title>EmployeeView</title>
</head>

<body>
<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("New Employee", "CreateEdit")
</p>
<table>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CreateEdit", new { id = item.Id })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

I have a method in my controller to handle the links:

```
public ActionResult CreateEdit(int? employeeId)
{
     if (employeeId is Int32)
     {
            int id = (Int32)employeeId;
            Employee e = er.GetById(id);
            return View(e);
     }

     else return View();

}
```

But employeeId is always null, even if I click on the link "Edit".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the link you pass the id as `id`.
Then in your view you have the name of the id as 'employeeId'.
They should be the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can do 1 of 2 things here.  Keep you helper method code as is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CreateEdit", new { id = item.Id })
```

..and then change your action method to look like this:

```
public ActionResult CreateEdit(int id)
{
     // Do what needs to be done
}
```

Or keep your action method as is:

```
public ActionResult CreateEdit(int? employeeId)
{
     // Do what needs to be done
}
```

..and then change your helper's code to:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "CreateEdit", new { employeeId = item.Id })
```

I hope this helps clarify things.

Comment: The first way does not work, there is an error: "The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult CreateEdit(Int32)'" when I use the "New Employee" link

Comment: It should work but then you just need to change your input parameter as is in my code.  They need to be exactly the same.